# Is there a way to use wait() or interrupt() without Syncronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

Say I have a thread running and I want to have it wait then get interrupted so that it will run again. However, for my assignment I am not allowed to use the `Synchronized` tag for my method. Is there another way I can do what I want either using `wait()` or possibly another built-in method? Or is it more complicated than that?
Thanks!

```
 public void run()
   {     
     int counter = 0;
     Thread t = new Thread();

     while(counter < 1){
     sleepTime = generator.nextInt((3000-200)+1)+200;
     withdrawAmount = generator.nextInt(50-1+1)+1;
     balance = BalanceCall.getBalance();
     if ((balance - withdrawAmount) > 0){
     t.interrupt();

     balance = BalanceCall.updateBalance(withdrawAmount, "Withdraw");
     System.out.print("         " + threadName + " withdraws $" + withdrawAmount + "        Balance is $" + balance + "\n");
     }

     else{
        System.out.print("          " + threadName + " withdraws $" + withdrawAmount + " Withdrawal - Blocked - Insufficient Funds\n");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     try {
         Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
     } 

     catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
   } // end method run
```

Comment: You don't have to synchronise a method, you can synchronise a block of code on a common monitor lock. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  A `CountDownLatch` "may" be another solution or even using something like `AtomicBoolean` or `ReentrantLock`

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE)`. The Thread.sleep method sleeps given number of milliseconds. `Long.MAX_VALUE` milliseconds is practically infinite (hundreds of millions of years). However sleep will be interrupted by `Thread.interrupt()`.

Comment: I have tried doing this, but I get the error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method interrupt() from the type Thread".  Then I tried making an object of Thread like `Thread t = new Thread();` and calling `t.interrupt();` but this wont interrupt my `Thread.sleep(10000);`